# how to write a code for 2 stage game?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, istgame

I am a student, and got the following question:
A market is characterized by a demand function Q = 1−P and by a single firm with constant marginal cost c. The monopolist is facing potential entry from a new firm having the same marginal cost but an additional fixed cost of entry F = 0.1. If the incumbent accepts the entry passively, then Cournot competition is played. However, the monopolist can threaten to produce the competitive output (i.e., the quantity such that P = c) so that the new entrant will make losses if it enters the market. If the new firm does not enter, the incumbent behaves as a monopolist.

Question:
Using the extensive form representation, describe this entry game as a two-stage game where in the first stage the new entrant decides whether to enter or not, and in the second stage the incumbent firm decides whether to be passive or aggressive in case of entry, while it does nothing in case the new firm does not enter the market.

I tried to write the code, as following:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thin,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
every circle node/.style={minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=0mm}]

\node[circle,draw,label=above:$Firm n$] (root) {}
child {node [circle,fill,label=above:$Firm m$] {}
child {node {$$$\frac{1}{90}, \frac{1}{9}$$$}
edge from parent
node[left] {$Cournot$}}
child {node {$$$-\frac{1}{10}, 0$$$}
edge from parent
node[right] {$Aggressive$}}
edge from parent
node[left] {$Enter$}}
child { node [circle,fill,label=above:$Firm m$] {}
edge from parent
node[right] {$Not Enter$}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

but still could not know how to write the answer for the right side (0,1/4)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try? There should be already quite a few examples on this site that can serve as a starting point. Where did you get stuck? Please try to come up with some [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can work with.

Comment: i wrote the code for the left side, but could not know how to write it for the right side

Comment: If you already tried something, please show it. There are several ways to approach this and it is most helpful to you if you get help with what you have so far. Also, this site is not meant to be a human-powered image-to-Ti*k*Z conversion tool. Therefore, you should always show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code what you tried so far, as no one likes to keyin your text

Comment: I added the details of the questions, if any one could help on this, i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You should always provide a *complete* (that is, compilable) code example. We won't help you with solving you homework here, but we can help you with optimizing your code. Some first hints: Do not use `$...$` to italicize text. Use `\itshape ...` or `\textit{...}` instead. Why triple `$$$...$$$`? You might be interested in the `forest` package, but you can also create the tree like you do. I would, however, simplify things and, for example, just use `child { node [label=below:{$\frac{1}{90}, \frac{1}{9}$}] {\itshape Cournot} }`.

Comment: Are you allowed to ask for help here? I'm guessing you're asking for help with typesetting, whereas it's the content which is being assessed, but it would be good to be clear about that. Also, can you make your code compilable?

Comment: What is the right side meant to look like? Forest or istgame will make your life easier if you need to draw several of these.

Comment: @Hanan, to understand what me and other commentators here are missing, kindly apply this scheme: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, all of you, i managed to work it out through one of the question here in the site, will provide the full answer in the question itself later today

Comment: Please don't do that. If you figured out the answer yourself, post it as an answer to your question and link the other question you used.